# How do I invoke Clock-Domain Crossing in Questa CDC?

Tags: questasim

Is there a command to invoke Clock Domain Crossing (CDC) in Questa CDC?
I am looking for something like in midelsim .vsim for simulation, in cadence simvision.

Comment: The [tag:cdc] tag is extremely ambiguous. I guess this is somehow related to VLSI design ...? Please review for better tags and [edit] accordingly.

Comment: I have cleaned up your title a bit. I am guessing you mean "Clock Domain Crossing" in your question. Based on your use of "Questa CDC" I am guessing you are using questasim, and I have tagged your question based on that. As it stands, your question is very unclear and is missing a lot of context. Please [edit] your question and add extra information on what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Any of these should work from a Linux command prompt.  Newer versions use qverify.
GUI:

```
qverify &   
qcdc &
```

Batchmode:

```
qverify -c -do $WORK/cdc/scripts/cdc.do -od $WORK/cdc/results   
qcdc -c -do $WORK/cdc/scripts/cdc.do -od $WORK/cdc/results
```